# Thinkpad T530 with Intel HD 4000 and Nvidia NVS 5400M Gamma adjust not working

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, thinkpad, graphics, gamma

Some process seems to have a deathgrip on my laptop's color settings, specifically the gamma adjust. I'm trying to adjust the gamma on my laptop because my outboard monitor is too dark for my taste, and I'm having a hard time. Every time I adjust the gamma settings -- whether it's through Nvidia Control Panel or through Windows Display Calibration, it gets reset within about a second of my making the adjustment. I have tried disabling the Intel Common User Interface processes with msconfig.exe, and have checked "Use Windows Display Calibration" in Windows Color Management, to no effect.

I am running a Thinkpad T530 with Intel HD4000 and NVIDIA NVS 5400M graphics. I just upgraded my drivers today, and it hasn't made a difference.

What is my problem?